# Indesign Script JS: Edit Document TextFrame Content and get back to Dialog Window

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I want to edit some textframe content in Indesign documents by JS. But I cannot find any solution to get any change with feedback in Dialog Window.
So I just have a simple document with one Textframe with name **test**

*I just paste relevant parts to keep it simple, in my Dialog I have lot of settings...*

```
var w = new Window ("dialog","DialogTitle");  
    var changeText = w.add("button", [0,0,150,20], "change test Text");  
    changeText.onClick = function(){ 
        w.close(1);
    } 

    var result = w.show(); 

    if (result == 1){
        myFrame = app.activeDocument.textFrames.itemByName("test");
        myFrame.contents = "New Text";
        var result = w.show(0);    //Here I want to reopen the Window w
        //Is not working
    }
```

you could not make any changes while Dialog is shown. But how I get Dialog back?

Comment: A dialog is shown but it's empty (no element no title) and not my expected w Dialog

Comment: It does not say in the reference, but may be it is the window object being destroyed when on close method. I would try to run exactly the same window creation code again.

Comment: Hello Nicolai Kant, thank you for comment. I tryed to do this with a Function and its working, but I don't think it's a good solution.

Comment: Well, working solution is a good solution. I tried to trace it and window is not destroyed, object still exists after close. I think there is a second window off screen, which locks my inDesign after the script is run.

Answer (score 1):

To keep your custom window and UI access define this window as "palette" instead of "dialog". 
Your script 1st directive supposes to call your custom targetengine as well, something like: `#targetengine "mysession"`