# Indesign javascript ERROR: MODAL DIALOG OR ALERT IS ACTIVE adobe extendscript toolkit

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

I try to run my javascript code by indesign but there is the error:
MODAL DIALOG OR ALERT IS ACTIVE.

Who knows how to solve this problem?

```
 #target "InDesign"

 w = new Window ('dialog'); 

 magicButton = w.add ("button", undefined, "Buttton");
 magicButton.onClick = main

 w.show ();

 function main(){

 var myDocument = app.activeDocument
 myDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = 
 MeasurementUnits.PIXELS;
 myDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = 
 MeasurementUnits.PIXELS;
 }
```

Comment: Well, the error message states that there must be a model dialog or an alert open. So, you should switch to InDesign, make sure that all these dialogs and alerts are closed and then you should be able to run the script.

Comment: The problem arises precisely when using the interface. If you run code without an interface UI (buttons, fields, etc), the commands are executed. I need an interface through which the user sets the values and they are transferred to the script code. Now this is not possible due to an error. I thought that maybe you need to bury the script window (it is the only one open in the program) but this does not help

Comment: You cannot run such commands *inside* a modal dialog. Either set some variables so you can run the requested code once the dialog is closed, or change its type to `'palette'` (which, all in all, behaves much different). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/33660013

Comment: palette do not run((

Comment: It is very strange because similar code runs by adobe illustrator and photoshop (dialog type window)

Comment: My apologies, please disregard my comment above. Of course the error that shows up relates to the actual window that is still open. I will write a proper answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens, because the window with the button is still open. And while that is the case, the document cannot be changed.

To make it work, you could use the button to just close the window and then let the main function run right afterwards:

```js
#target "InDesign"

w = new Window('dialog');

magicButton = w.add ("button", undefined, "Buttton");
magicButton.onClick = function() {
  w.close();
}

w.show();

main();

function main(){

  // ... do stuff with the document etc.

}
```

Note that more typically you would add both an `OK` and `Cancel` button to your window and then depending on which button the user presses, you would execute your function or not.

If you need to have the window stay open (altough I don't see how this would make any sense in the example you have given), you would neet to create a window of type `palette` instead of `dialog`. In this case you will also have to create a target engine, else the window will not show up:

```js
#targetengine session

w = new Window('palette');

// ... and so on
```